# Does glass undergo internal damage in a similar way to wood?

Tags: forces, material-science, glass

Does glass undergo internal damage in a similar way to wood when struck hard, even if it doesn't visibly break, and is this damage accumulated gradually over time, or does it occur as a binary response, unlike wood.

Answer (score 26):

No, wood and glass fail in completely different ways.

Wood is a *composite structure* consisting of cellulose fibers held together with lignin glue. In wood, an impact force breaks the lignin loose from the cellulose  and the cellulose fibers are then free to slip past one another without taking up any tension load. the tension loads then are felt by the lignin which cannot sustain them, and the piece of wood slowly and gradually comes apart under load.

Glass is a *classically brittle* substance which possesses no plastic deformation mechanisms at room temperature. An impact load cannot be distributed over a larger area through plastic deformation and is instead concentrated as a near-point load which locally exceeds the tensile strength of the glass, which initiates a series of cracks which then travel through the part at about the speed of sound in the glass, which then explodes into a cloud of jagged fragments.

Comment: Can the series of cracks be invisible? If I drop a glass and it did not break is it as good as before the drop or is there is some amount of effect occurred after the drop. Is there any test that can determine if an unbroken glass is dropped or not?

Comment: @Talespin_Kit, good glass is rendered fragile by the presence of *microcracks* (i.e., tiny scratches) in its surface. these happen mostly by abrasion and not by droppage. Here is a test for microcracks: take a perfectly dry glass. get you a bottle of your favorite carbonated beverage (beer works really well) and gently pour the glass full. microcracks will be revealed as teeny points on the surface of the glass from which streams of bubbles extend upwards towards the surface. photographers deliberately microscratch beer glasses before filling them, to obtain a goodly showing of those bubbles.

Comment: and yes, the cracks are far too small to see without a microscope.

Comment: I find your comment even more enlightening than your post, although I don't know how you might work that into the post.

Comment: @PasserBy, I don't know either. Perhaps I could ask a question about that and answer it myself (BTW the rules here do allow you to answer your own question).

Comment: @nielsnielsen I've owned a few beer glasses where the bottom of the glass has been laser etched for this exact reason.

Comment: I remember once when a 2L glass soda pop bottle fell out of my fridge onto a concrete floor. The first time it hit the ground, it bounced quite satisfyingly, but remained intact. On the second contact, it shattered and dispersed its contents rather spectacularly. Explanation?

Comment: @d3jones, the first impact with the concrete put scratches into the bottle which act as stress magnifiers and crack initiation sites. second drop then stressed the initiation sites and kablooey.

Comment: @JimmyJames, the beer ad photographers used to shake ball bearings around inside the glass to pit it, and create initiation sites.

Comment: @nielsnielsen Sorry, I didn't mean the laser etching was for ads, just to create bubbles.  It works really well.